# Multiple Group by in SQL

Tags: sql, group-by

I have a table like this.

```
Year        Month       TenDays     Pay    
========================================
2015         8          2           12     
2016         8          1           43
2016         8          2           11
2016         9          1           22
2016         9          2           33
2016         9          3           4
2016         9          3           25
```

I want to have SQL query that calculate sum of 'Pay' as 'TotalTenDays' group by 'year' and 'Month' and 'TenDays'
and also calculate sum of 'Pay' as 'TotalMonth' group by 'year' and 'Month'.

I can do that with "union all" but ***I am searching for a way without using union and 'with cte as()'.***
Is it Possible?

Expected table must be like this:

```
Year        Month       TenDays    TotalTenDays   TotalMonth
====================================================================
2015         8          2          12             12
2016         8          1          43             54
2016         8          2          11             54
2016         9          1          22             84
2016         9          2          33             84
2016         9          3          29             84
```

Comment: It's doable; you need to create two sub-queries that do the aggregations, and then join the results of those two sub-queries.  Each sub-query will have a different GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer depends on the database dialect.

The first 4 columns are standard SQL `GROUP BY` logic, i.e. `GROUP BY Year, Month, TenDays` with a `SUM(Pay) AS TotalTenDays` result column.

The `TotalMonth` column is best done with a *windowing function* using the `OVER` clause, but that's only if the SQL dialect supports it.

E.g. for SQL Server, you can do this:

```sql
SELECT Year, Month, TenDays
     , SUM(Pay) AS TotalTenDays
     , SUM(SUM(Pay)) OVER (PARTITION BY Year, Month) AS TotalMonth
  FROM MyTable
 GROUP BY Year, Month, TenDays
 ORDER BY Year, Month, TenDays
```

See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e60e8/1) for running query using MS SQL Server 2017.

---

If the SQL dialect doesn't support windowing functions, then suggestion in [comment by Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48046455/multiple-group-by-in-sql#comment83064300_48046455) is a good alternative:

> You need to create two sub-queries that do the aggregations, and then join the results of those two sub-queries. Each sub-query will have a different `GROUP BY` clause.

```sql
SELECT a.Year, a.Month, a.TenDays, a.TotalTenDays, b.TotalMonth
  FROM ( SELECT Year, Month, TenDays
              , SUM(Pay) AS TotalTenDays
           FROM MyTable
          GROUP BY Year, Month, TenDays
       ) a
  JOIN ( SELECT Year, Month
              , SUM(Pay) AS TotalMonth
           FROM MyTable
          GROUP BY Year, Month
       ) b ON b.Year = a.Year
          AND b.Month = a.Month
 ORDER BY a.Year, a.Month, a.TenDays
```

See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e60e8/5) for running query using MySQL 5.6.